# Proper usage of MySQL variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a big MySQL query which is formed with PHP.
I don't like that this big **IF statement** repeats 4 times in a query (saved in `$endTrialDate` variable).

And I want to make it shorter and nicer, just using MySQL variables.

My Query **(EDITED AND SIMPLIFIED)**:

```php
$endTrialDateCondition = "IF(ec.extend_trial_type LIKE 'week',
        ADDDATE(ec.start_contract, (7 * ec.extend_trial_time)),
          IF(ec.extend_trial_type LIKE 'day',
            ADDDATE(ec.start_contract, ec.extend_trial_time),
            ADDDATE(ec.start_contract, INTERVAL ec.extend_trial_time MONTH)
          )
        )";

$endTrialDate = "(SUBDATE((".$endTrialDateCondition."), 1))";

$finalQuery = "SELECT e.firstname_employe, e.lastname_employe,
  ".$endTrialDate." as end_trial_date
    FROM employe_contract ec
    LEFT JOIN employe e ON ec.id_employe = e.id_employe
    WHERE ".$endTrialDate." >= ?
    AND ".$endTrialDate." <= ?
    ORDER BY ".$endTrialDate.", e.lastname_employe, e.firstname_employe";
```

When I tried to modify my query like: (using variable @end_trial_date)

```php
$finalQuery = "SELECT e.firstname_employe, e.lastname_employe,
  @end_trial_date := ".$endTrialDate." as end_trial_date
    FROM employe_contract ec
    LEFT JOIN employe e ON ec.id_employe = e.id_employe
    WHERE @end_trial_date >= ?
    AND @end_trial_date <= ?
    ORDER BY @end_trial_date, e.lastname_employe, e.firstname_employe";
```

end_trial_date in results was `NULL`, so nothing was found.

How to make this query shorter?

Comment: This is a complex query and we have no idea how your database is structured or what the point of the query is. I think you either have to give us more details, or you won't get an (good) answer.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I think I can simplify that.  
The main problem that I have. When I assign IF STATEMENT to variable, it shows me NULL in results.  
I thought it was like not assigned in moment of comparsion.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think variables in MySQL are global, and you cannot use them inside a `SELECT` query on a row by row basis as you are. Or, to put it in other terms: the `ORDER BY` is performed after all the rows have been selected, so the variable there won't have the content you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this:

```
$finalQuery = "SELECT e.firstname_employe, e.lastname_employe,
 ".$endTrialDate." as end_trial_date
    FROM employe_contract ec
    LEFT JOIN employe e ON ec.id_employe = e.id_employe
    WHERE end_trial_date >= ?
    AND end_trial_date <= ?
    ORDER BY end_trial_date, e.lastname_employe, e.firstname_employe";
```

I'm not sure this will execute, but it is better than what you had. Basically the `as` gives you your variable that works row by row.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work.
Unknown column 'end_trial_date' in 'where clause'

Comment: Yes, I was afraid of something like that. The expressions in the select are only evaluated after the where's have been done.

Comment: I've also tried to set variable in where clause.
But it was also not working as expected. Not NULL, but just empty row. (1 found but with totally empty fields)

Comment: Yes, a query runs over the data several times, first to do the `WHERE` then to do the expressions on the selected rows, and finally to order them. global variables can therefore not be used. Another solution could be that you store the `end_trial_date` in the table, or in a temporary table, and then use it from there.

Comment: That's interesting. Probably will leave that task for some better moment, thx for your time